# JPA select from multiple tables error

Tags: java, jpa

I am new to JPA and I try to select from three table I get error. I try to select only product that with selected category, however the product is under product subcategory and the subcategory is under category table.

product foreign key to product subcategory
product subcategory foreign key to product category

How to fix this? Thanks.

```
public List<Product> findByCategoryID(int CategoryID, String status) {
    query = mgr.createQuery("SELECT a FROM Product a, ProductCategory b, ProductSubcategory c WHERE b.categoryid=c.categoryid AND a.subcategoryid=c.subcategoryid AND b.categoryid = ?1 AND a.productstatus = ?2");
    query.setParameter("1", CategoryID);
    query.setParameter("2", status);
    List productList = query.getResultList();
    return productList;
}
```

This is the error log

```
Severe:   Local Exception Stack:   
Exception [EclipseLink-6076] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.QueryException  
Exception Description: Object comparisons can only be used with OneToOneMappings.  Other mapping comparisons must be done through query keys or direct attribute level comparisons.   
Mapping: [org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.DirectToFieldMapping[categoryid-->PRODUCTCATEGORY.CATEGORYID]]   
Expression: [  
Query Key categoryid  
Base model.ProductCategory]  
Query: ReadAllQuery(referenceClass=Product jpql="SELECT a FROM Product a, ProductCategory b, ProductSubcategory c WHERE b.categoryid=c.categoryid AND a.subcategoryid=c.subcategoryid AND b.categoryid = ?1 AND a.productstatus = ?2")  
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.QueryException.unsupportedMappingForObjectComparison(QueryException.java:1170)  
    at org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.DatabaseMapping.buildObjectJoinExpression(DatabaseMapping.java:292)  
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.expressions.RelationExpression.normalize(RelationExpression.java:832)  
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.expressions.CompoundExpression.normalize(CompoundExpression.java:224)  
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.expressions.CompoundExpression.normalize(CompoundExpression.java:224)  
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.expressions.CompoundExpression.normalize(CompoundExpression.java:224)  
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.expressions.SQLSelectStatement.normalize(SQLSelectStatement.java:1449)  
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.ExpressionQueryMechanism.buildNormalSelectStatement(ExpressionQueryMechanism.java:549)  
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.ExpressionQueryMechanism.prepareSelectAllRows(ExpressionQueryMechanism.java:1720)  
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReadAllQuery.prepareSelectAllRows(ReadAllQuery.java:813)  
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReadAllQuery.prepare(ReadAllQuery.java:744)  
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.checkPrepare(DatabaseQuery.java:661)  
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.checkPrepare(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:901)  
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.checkPrepare(DatabaseQuery.java:613)  
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.buildEJBQLDatabaseQuery(EJBQueryImpl.java:194)  
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.buildEJBQLDatabaseQuery(EJBQueryImpl.java:116)  
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.<init>(EJBQueryImpl.java:102)  
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.<init>(EJBQueryImpl.java:86)  
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.createQuery(EntityManagerImpl.java:1603)  
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.EntityManagerWrapper.createQuery(EntityManagerWrapper.java:456)  
    at model.ProductService.findByCategoryID(ProductService.java:45)  
    at controller.RetrieveProductList.processRequest(RetrieveProductList.java:45)  
    at controller.RetrieveProductList.doGet(RetrieveProductList.java:82)  
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)  
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)  
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)  
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)  
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)  
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)  
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)  
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)  
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)  
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:415)  
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:282)  
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)  
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)  
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)  
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)  
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)  
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)  
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)  
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)  
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)  
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)  
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)  
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)  
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)  
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)  
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)  
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)  
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)  
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)  
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JPA retrieve all the objects that are associated to the first one, so you don't have to do

```
query = mgr.createQuery("SELECT a FROM Product a, ProductCategory b,
ProductSubcategory c WHERE b.categoryid=c.categoryid AND 
a.subcategoryid=c.subcategoryid AND b.categoryid = ?1 AND a.productstatus = ?2");
```

If your entities have the relations correctly you just need to do

```
query = mgr.createQuery("SELECT a FROM Product a WHERE 
a.b.categoryid = ?1 AND a.productstatus = ?2;
```